# InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touchable window or gesture monitor

Tags: android, android-emulator, apple-m1

I have a problem with the Android emulator (v30.9.4) on M1 Max Macbook.
Sometimes the emulator stops accepting touch input in the current foreground Activity (can be even in a system Activity), without a clear pattern.
I'm not 100% sure it's because of M1, but I have never had these problems on any other machine.

The Logcat shows these logs on each tap in the Activity:

```
I/InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touchable window or gesture monitor at (827, 950) in display 0.
I/InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touched foreground window in display 0 or gesture monitor to receive it.
```

I have tried various AVD configurations, 29/30/31 SDK levels, both with Google APIs and without them.
The quick boot is turned off.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer